# Why does the "package" has a "package" in the Doxygen tree?

Tags: python, doxygen

I generate the documentation of my Python code from the docstrings via [Doxygen](https://www.doxygen.nl/index.html) (1.9.1) in addition with [doxypypy](https://github.com/Feneric/doxypypy) (git version from today).

My project is called `Project` and the packages name in it (which should be `import`ed) is `mypackage`. When I look into the tree sidebar of the generated html it looks like this:

```
└── Project
    └── Packages
        └── Packages
            └──mypackages
```

The two *packages* are linking to the same target: `../html/namespaces.html`.

The files and folders are structured like this

```
Project
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── docs
    └── ...
└── src
    ├── mypackage
    │   ├── a.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── _mypackage.py
    ├── setup.cfg
    └── setup.py
```

The `Doxyfile` is located in `Project/docs`, `doxygen` is run in there and use `../src/mypackage` as `INPUT` directory.

## More details

### `__init__.py`

```
__version__ = '0.0.1a'

from ._mypackage import *
```

### `_mypackage.py`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Example __init__.py short.

Now some longer with multiple lines. Here
comes the scond line.
"""

def foo(bar):
    """
    This is foo() in mypackage.

    Args:
        bar (str): A paramenter.

    Returns:
        (int): Fixed seven.
    """
    print(bar)
    return 7
```

### `a.py`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""This is mypackage.a
"""
import mypackage



def bar(bar):
    """
    This is the function named bar.

    The function calls `mypackage.foo()` and returns an 'a'.

    Paramters:
        bar (str): Just a parameter.

    Returns:
        str: Just an 'a'.
    """
    mypackage.foo(bar)
    return('a')
```

### Some (maybe) related `Doxyfile` settings

```
BRIEF_MEMBER_DESC      = YES
REPEAT_BRIEF           = YES
ALWAYS_DETAILED_SEC    = NO
FULL_PATH_NAMES        = YES
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF      = NO
PYTHON_DOCSTRING       = YES
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = NO
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_JAVA   = YES
OPTIMIZE_FOR_FORTRAN   = NO
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_VHDL   = NO
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_SLICE  = NO
MARKDOWN_SUPPORT       = YES
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
EXTRACT_PACKAGE        = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES  = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = YES
EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES   = NO
RESOLVE_UNNAMED_PARAMS = YES
HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS     = NO
HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES     = NO
HIDE_FRIEND_COMPOUNDS  = NO
HIDE_IN_BODY_DOCS      = NO
INPUT                  = ../src/mypackage
FILE_PATTERNS          =
RECURSIVE              = YES
FILTER_PATTERNS        = *.py=./py_filter
GENERATE_HTML          = YES

GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = YES
```

I opened an [Issue](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/9192) about that.

Comment: Can you please give a small complete example (with the "import" etc.). Note the current doxygen version is 1.9.3 (might have some influence on the results).

Comment: I see in the current master (after adding `GEBNERATE_TREEVIEW=YES` and removing `FILTER_PATTERNS...` the same behavior no direct idea. Maybe best to post an issue in the doxygen issue tracker with all the relevant information.